# SQLDeveloper: execute current line without highlighting

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Toad one can easily execute current line without highlighting it. Let say, you have a worksheet like this:

```
select * from item -- cursor here


select * from product
```

When I click on `CTRL+Enter` I want only the line where the cursor is to be executed. In SQLDeveloper, if there is no second line, `CTRL+Enter` works as I want. Basically, I want to do the same as described [here](http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=20807), but for some reason, I can't find the `Tools -> Preferences -> Window Types -> SQL Window and check "AutoSelect statement"`  in the version of the SQLDeveloper I am using: `4.0.0.13`, build `Build MAIN: 13.80`.

Seems like, this functionality is taken out in the `4.x` of Oracle SQLDeveloper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who also wonder about the same thing, here is what you gotta do. End each statement with `;` and it works.

```
select * from item
;

select * from product;
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't... In Oracle SQL Developer version 3.2.20.10, it still highlights the entire worksheet.

Answer (score 18):

If you have a block (anonymous or such) of code before your sql statement, make sure to end with forward slash, for the CTRL+enter to work.

CTRL+Enter on the select sysdate statement below works in second example below, but not on the first example.

Example 1:

```
begin
NULL;
end;

select sysdate from dual; -- press CTRL+Enter on this statement
```

Example 2:

```
begin
NULL;
end;
/

select sysdate from dual; -- press CTRL+Enter on this statement
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually the best option is mentioned here : 
http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=46683

> 1) Press Ctrl-F8 when the cursor is on the statement. Now only the
>   current statement is executed. You can assign a different key through
>   the preferences (Tools > Preferences > Key Configuration > "SQL
>   Window: Execute current statement").
>
> 2) Enable the "AutoSelect statement" preference (Tools > Preferences >
>   SQL Window). Now the standard execute function will automatically
>   select the current statement under the cursor and execute it. To
>   execute multiple statements you now have to explicitly select them
>   first in the editor, or use Ctrl-F8.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar situation where Ctrl+Enter shortcut stopped working for executing any statement and had to highlight the entire statement for executing it.

**How it worked:**
(i) By removing/commenting out all the comments in the worksheet i.e. just have only the Sql statements in the worksheet, if at all you have put any statements/comments in the worksheet for your understanding, just disable those and then Ctrl+Enter starts working.

PS: I didn't do any other changes apart from this to make this shortcut work.

Cheers