# Oracle SQL Developer - Ctrl+Enter runs whole worksheet instead of current line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, shortcut

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.3.16, and since a few weeks, the shortcut  Ctrl+Enter doesn't execute the current line or statement anymore, except for when I highlight it, but instead does run my whole worksheet. Using the green button on the top, which is supposed to only run the current line results in the same behaviour (except for when the line is highlighted). Hovering over the button still reveals the tooltip "Run Statement (Ctrl+Enter)". A colleague of mine does get this problem too.

I also looked into the Preferences->Shortcut Keys menu, but the shortcut set for running a statement is still Ctrl+Enter.

Anyone knows what's wrong with my SQL Developer?

Comment: Are you talking about a worksheet with independent SQL statements, or a PL/SQL block that's you're trying to run individual parts of?

Comment: It's independent SQL statements that I am trying to execute.

Answer (score 3):

Every SQL statement in SQL Developer should have semicolon `;` otherwise ctrl+Enter would execute will execute entire worksheet.
Suppose for example I have two SQL statements:
1.`select * from emp` without semicolon `;`

2.`UPDATE EMP SET DEPT_ID=10;` WITH SEMICOLON `;`
Then it will execute both statement simultaneously for that you should have semicolon after each SQL statement.

Comment: I end every statement with semicolon, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @lioxo See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced it too. Usually you'll have PL/SQL block above the SQL code you are trying to execute. Comment out the PL/SQL block which is DECLARE, BEGIN without ending in semicolon creating this issue. So commenting the PL/SQL block in worksheet should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590199/1599699): if it doesn't work even with a semicolon after the line like it didn't for me (Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.20.10), you need to put a '/' after each command if you want to execute them all independently, e.g.:

```
blahblah;
/

blahblah;
/
```

Think of the '/' as the real terminator/separator here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I kinda solved it.

Since I'm not an administrator on the computers at work I couldn't install a new client, so I downloaded the SQL Developer in version 4.0.3.16 a while ago and just ran it locally from my user directory.
Meanwhile the client 4.0.3.16 is installed on the OS and when using this client I don't get this bug. 
Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences->Shortcut Keys menu set for running a statement is still Ctrl+Enter.

If you put a ";" at the end of the sql statements, and select the "AutoSelect statement" in the SQL preferences, it will only execute the SQL that the cursor is on.